# Posting link to Page now includes thumbnails when none is set

Tags: image, facebook-graph-api, thumbnails, posts

As of this morning (12th July) a server script we used to automatically add updates to a facebook page is including a thumbail of the website logo.

We add an image ourselves if there is a suitable one - but leave the picture variable as blank otherwise.

As of today Facebook grabs the image set in the webpage og:image setting (or the first off the page if that is disabled) and adds it to the post update.

Net result, every single post this morning has the site logo as an image, and it looks a right mess.

Question - how can I set the image variable to NULL (or equiv) so that it wont try to generate a thumbnail where one is not explicitly defined?

Thanks

(Every help search I make returns results explaining how to add a thumbail - I want to get rid of it!)

Answer (score 0):

A slight workaround has been to define the thumbnail image as a 1x1 png file, which forces it to use that instead of grabbing the site logo off the linked webpage.

Would still prefer to find a way of forcing it to not use a thumbnail at all though - as was the default behaviour until a couple of days ago.